# Blur My Shell Overview is not working

Tags: 22.04, desktop-background, activities-overview

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Blur My Shell is turned on and it's not blurring the Overview

[image: Overview] not blurry

[image: Blur My Shell] toggle is turned on

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The background of applications is grey instead of blurry even though I turn it on

Blur My Shell > Overview Tab > Toggle is On